# Operadores lógicos y Ciclo While

Tags: python, while, operador

Estoy programando una calculadora y al definir un ciclo while con operadores lógicos solo reconoce un operando (suma) de las 5 que hay. Además al reconocer un solo operando que es la suma, solo se realiza ésta operación.
Necesito saber como puedo arreglar este problema para que reconozca cada operando (+, -, /, * y **) y este haga su respectiva operación.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, comparte tu código como texto, pues nadie puede replicar nada a partir de una imagen y nadie acá adivina, todos acá probamos el código de los demás para ayudarnos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: @Alfabravo, ahí esta para que puedas ver y/o descargar: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rIFs4UfXuio__c8rtvhcnzvbUvpZqrHN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Te recomiendo ver [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular preguntas que reciban respuesta rápida. Si borras el archivo de tu drive porque necesitas espacio, la pregunta se vuelve inútil para todos los que puedan tener el mismo problema en el futuro. Las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas :)  Sigue el consejo de gbianchi y revisa el enlace del recorrido. Ayuda a aprovechar mejor el sitio!

Comment: No pongas un link al código; edita tu pregunta para agregar el código en texto.

Comment: Al margen de la pregunta, un consejo: en vez de anidar una y otra vez un `if` dentro de un `else` utiliza `elif`. Eso ayudará a mantener los niveles de indentación razonables.

Answer (score 2):

Estás usando mal las comparaciones lógicas. Tienes una comparación donde operador es diferente de "+", LUEGO tienes unas expresiones separadas por AND que se evalúan muy diferente a lo que esperas.

Decir `a != b AND c AND d` no significa que compares a con b, con c y con d. Lo que pasa es que

- comparas a con b
- evalúas si c es verdadero o falso
- evalúas si d es verdadero o falso

Así pues, el intérprete python no puede adivinar que lo que quieres es comparar la variable con cada una de esas cadenas y debes decírselo de forma explícita.

`a !=b AND a != c AND a != d`